# Suspiciouser and suspiciouser

Tags: story, rebus

> I was sitting in the hotel lobby waiting for my taxi when I noticed a pretty suspicious-looking guy enter the building. Fedora and sunglasses, in October? Long trench coat and black leather gloves? Immediately the *Mission: Impossible* theme started playing in my head.
>
> The man walked up to a woman who was sitting in the cafeteria, silently passed her a small note, and promptly walked out the door. The woman took a look at the note. After reading it she picked up her things and headed for the elevators. She threw the note in a nearby garbage can.
>
> By this point I was intrigued what the note might say, but I don't want to be nosy and it was none of my business. So I stayed in my seat and patiently waited for my ride.
>
> Just kidding. As soon as she disappeared in the elevator I was head first in the wastebin looking for that note. Here's what the message looked like:
>
> [image]
>
> I have no idea how to interpret this, and it's killing me now. What can this mysterious message mean??

Comment: I'm surprised at the pristine condition the note is in after having been thrown into the trash ;-)

Comment: @M.Herzkamp Is it surprising or... *suspicious*? Hmm!

Comment: Nice job on [getting the pip pattern right](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60598/36023) on that die, by the way!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The message reads:

> **Hotel bar. Six o'clock**

The components are:

> The four-pointed compass rose is the emblem of Nato. In the Nato Phonetic alphabet, the H corresponds to **Hotel**. Brıgıtte is Brigitte Bardot, of course, but without the dots, so just **bar**. The arrow points to the side opposite the one on the die, which is **six**. And the last image shows a water molecule where the oxygen atom **O** has been replaced with a **clock**.
>
>  I first read the second part as bar and the punctuation dot, but Agent Bass pointed out that the dots on the i's were missing; thanks for that. (The silly little schoolboy in me calls these dots by their *real* name, [tittles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle).)

Comment: The distinctive typography of the word "Brıgıtte" may explain what happens to the latter half of the surname.

Comment: The second one is a bit obscure.

Comment: Whoa I'm amazed at how far-fetched some of these are, and people still manage justfine.

Comment: Yep, this is it. @Bass is correct that the rot13[qbgyrff v] was meant as part of the hint :)

Comment: Oh, yes, I noticed the typographical curiosity, but by the time I solved it, I had forgotten about it. For what it's worth, I spent a lot of time trying to find out what the first symbol was for; I wanted to make it a verb somehow.

Answer (score 6):

> The note means you should play Brigitte and heal him, while he is easy high-nooning 6 people :)

because:

> I have literally no idea or hobbies:
>  The H is in the east => eas
>  Brigitte is pretty self explaining
>  The playing cube shows 6, at least thats what's pointed to
>  and the clock shows 110% high noon with some H behind that
>  => 6 peopled nooned eas(y)(x2)
>  Do you pls understand this is satirical

Comment: Not sure if it will help you or not, but rot13(V guvax gur pybpx vf hfvat gur zbyrphyne ercerfragngvba bs jngre be U2B)

Comment: This is hilarious. I wish you had left out the last line of the explanation.